# Opacity toggle doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I have this code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
       $(".regcontainer").hide();
       $(".registrateimg").click(function(){
       $(".regcontainer").animate({
        height:"toggle",   
        opacity:"toggle"}
        ,"slow");});
    }
    );
</script>
```

The problem is that when I load the page the registration form is there and it must be hidden until click on the image , which class is registrateimg . I think my code is okay . I saw another topic similar to this but there the problem is that it was not used $(document).ready ... and here it is . I dont know where is my mistake .

Comment: _"when I load the page the registration form is there"_, well your opacity toggle isn't running on page load, it's running on `click`. If you want it to be hidden then give your form a `opacity:0` value in your css. Also if you have a `src` attribute set on a script tag, the code between the tags will not be run.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two script tags, one for loading jQuery, one for your own code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(".regcontainer").hide();
        $(".registrateimg").click(function(){
        $(".regcontainer").animate({
        height:"toggle",
        opacity:"toggle"}
        ,"slow");});
    }
    );
</script>
```

(also, you don't need the type="text/javascript" bit)

Comment: Glad to help!  If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 0):

you can use another way. The following methods will hide your element

```
$(".regcontainer").css("display","none");
```

or

```
$(".regcontainer").css('opacity', '0');
```

Comment: Thanks , but the idea was like that . I ll use it definetely in another project of mine . :)